# How to convert a string that is json or xml -like to a useable python object

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a data structure that is sent from another code, and I can't get the original datatype.

```
Item 1: 
    Name 1
        attribute1 = something1
        attribute2 = something2
    otherAttribute1 = otherthing1
    otherAttribute2 = otherthing2

Item 2: 
    Name 1
        attribute1 = something1
        attribute2 = something2
    otherAttribute1 = otherthing1
    otherAttribute2 = otherthing2
```

The data comes in as a unicode string like above.  It seems like json at first glance.  Other posts I can find are dealing with a string that is json but containing delimiter.  In this case there is just the spacing.

[image]

Comment: Without knowing the precise grammar rules of this data it can't be done reliably.

Comment: @MichaelButscher do you mean words or structure?  I added a picture, I think it is just the same as the one to the right, just missing quotes and brackets.  I guess I could count number of spaces and replace them by a bracket, but was hoping it was easier.

Comment: I mean the structure. For instance: Why is there a colon after the `Item`s but not after the `Name`s?

Comment: @MichaelButscher I see.  Well in this case its similar to an obj file.  Like the Item is the name of an object or object group, then the name is some individual object within that group and it has some attributes assigned to it.  I guess really i need to get the hierarchy into a subdict or something like that.